# Postgres logical replication & physical replication Coexist ??? question

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

I have a postgres logical replication between two postgres serverA and ServerB for certain tables. Can i succesfully configure Postgres physical replication for all tables (including the tables participating in logical replication) between postgres serverB and another postgres server - say ServerC ??. Are there any limitations ? Highly appreciate the answers

Comment: That will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, physical replication between PostgreSQL Server B and Server C is achievable while Server B is engaging in logical replication with Server A.

Both physical and logical replication can be configured at the same time. By specifying the `primary_conninfo` parameter, you may ensure that you have appropriately configured physical replication on Server B as the primary server for Server C. Consider PostgreSQL version compatibility between servers and be aware of potential conflicts if tables participating in logical replication on Server B are also replicated to Server C via physical replication. To ensure smooth replication processes, thoroughly evaluate the system and consider monitoring tools and cautious maintenance.